# ERROR running force:package:version:create: Invalid character in header content ["getApiVersion"]

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce

a. If the Dev Hub org doesn't have its "Unlocked and 2GP Packages" option enabled, you would get the error message Invalid character in header content ["getApiVersion"]. You may want to check that

b. This can be also caused due to lack of permissions on the user performing the operation. If you are using a Limited Access User Profile for performing the job and then make sure following permissions are part of your profile.

1. Create and Update Second-Generation Packages
2. Promote a package version to released

c. The error is might be also caused due to the custom code, please reach out to your internal developer to verify the same to investigate this further.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was the option c. Adding here to help the community